# Python создание таблицы (следующий ряд начинается со второго значения предыдущего ряда)

Tags: python, циклы, список, таблицы

Я совсем новичок в Python.
Подскажите, как лучше решить следующее
Есть список букв [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J] всего 10 букв.
Мне нужно представить этот ряд в виде таблицы 8 рядов 3 столбца,  но так чтобы каждый следующий ряд начинается со второго значения предыдущего ряда. 
То есть вот так: см картинку
 до последней буквы J.
Спасибо![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

for i in range(8):
    print(data[i: i+3])
```